# Vba code to click on 2nd page in webpage

Tags: vba

I am trying to click on 2nd page in webpage but no luck.Request you to please help me to solve this issue.

Here is the HTML for the button I am trying to click:

```html
<div class="pgdiv">
<span value="1" class="pgdes">  1</span>
<span value="2" class="pgsel">  2</span>
<span value="3" class="pgsel">  3</span>
<span value="4" class="pgsel">  4</span>
<span value="5" class="pgsel">  5</span>
<span value="6" class="pgsel">  6</span>
<span value="7" class="pgsel">  7</span>
<span value="8" class="pgsel">  8</span>
<span value="9" class="pgsel">  9</span>
<span style="width:72px" value="2" class="pgsel">Next »</span></div>
```

Here is my VBA code:

```
With ie.document
    Set elems = .getElementsByTagName("Span")
    For Each e In elems
        If (e.getAttribute("value") = "2") Then
            e.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next e
End With
```

Comment: Which bits not working, getting e or clicking it?

Comment: I am not able to click on 2nd page.

Comment: but e is what you expected?  try, `.fireevent("Click")`

Comment: Add `MsgBox` before `Exit For` for debug.

Comment: this might be a little more concise to use `querySelectorAll` something like `.querySelectorAll('[pgsel="2"]')`

Comment: Hi Nathan_Sav , i am geeting error-Run time error '-2147352319(80020101)'; i have try-With ie.document
Set elems = .getElementsByTagName("Span")
For Each e In elems
        If (e.getAttribute("value") = "2") Then
            e.FireEvent ("Click")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next e
End With

Comment: Hi All, Now its working fine-With ie.document
Set elems = .getElementsByTagName("Span")
For Each e In elems
        If (e.getAttribute("value") = "2") Then
            e.Click
'            Exit For
        End If
    Next e
End With